Implementing Dynamic Font Size Adjustment in Next.js 12 + Tailwind CSS for Accessibility
I have a website built using Next.js 12 and Tailwind CSS. It consists of dozens of pages and components.
We've received complaints from users about the font size being too small. To address this, we want to add an accessibility button to the website that allows users to adjust the font size across the entire site from any page.
Our website is structured using Next.js with Tailwind CSS utility classes extensively used for styling. The font sizes are controlled through classes like text-xs, text-sm, and text-md.
Specifically, when the user clicks the 'increase font size' button:

Font sizes with the class name text-xs should increase from 10px to 12px.
Font sizes with the class name text-sm should increase from 12px to 14px.
Font sizes with the class name text-md should increase from 14px to 16px.

Conversely, when the user clicks the 'decrease font size' button, we want the font sizes to decrease accordingly.
We aim to meet WCAG accessibility standards with this feature.
Given our extensive use of Tailwind CSS, we want to avoid adding individual class names for each font size change.
Could someone suggest an approach or provide guidance on how to implement this effectively considering our technology stack and accessibility requirements? If possible, including code snippets or examples would be greatly appreciated

I don't know if it's the right way but it's the way I'm doing here. We had the same complaint in my company and what I used was next-themes. You just need to create your provider like so:


'use client'

import { ThemeProvider as NextThemesProvider } from 'next-themes'

import { type ThemeProviderProps } from 'next-themes/dist/types'

const ThemeProvider = ({ children, ...props }: ThemeProviderProps) => {
  return <NextThemesProvider {...props}>{children}</NextThemesProvider>
}

export default ThemeProvider



After that, wrap this whole thing around your app like so:


<ThemeProvider
  attribute="class"
  defaultTheme="system"
  disableTransitionOnChange
  enableSystem
>
{your-components}
</ThemeProvider>



Now, go to your globals and add your font-sizes and the line-heights. Do not oversight the line-height, because in the config it only accepts array ([font, lineheight]). We'll see in a moment.


.big {
  // base tailwind font size + the rems, pxs you wanna add
  --text-xs: calc(0.75rem + 0.25rem);
  --text-sm: calc(0.875rem + 0.25rem);
  --text-base: calc(1rem + 0.25rem);
  --text-lg: calc(1.125rem + 0.25rem);
  --text-xl: calc(1.25rem + 0.25rem);
  --text-2xl: calc(1.5rem + 0.25rem);
  --text-3xl: calc(1.875rem + 0.25rem);
  --text-4xl: calc(2.25rem + 0.25rem);
  --text-5xl: calc(3rem + 0.25rem);
  --text-6xl: calc(3.75rem + 0.25rem);
  --text-7xl: calc(4.5rem + 0.25rem);
  --text-8xl: calc(6rem + 0.25rem);
  --text-9xl: calc(8rem + 0.25rem);

  --line-height-xs: calc(1rem + 0.25rem);
  --line-height-sm: calc(1.25rem + 0.25rem);
  --line-height-base: calc(1.5rem + 0.25rem);
  --line-height-lg: calc(1.75rem + 0.25rem);
  --line-height-xl: calc(1.75rem + 0.25rem);
  --line-height-2xl: calc(2rem + 0.25rem);
  --line-height-3xl: calc(2.25rem + 0.25rem);
  --line-height-4xl: calc(2.5rem + 0.25rem);
}



I had a real problem going back to the normal font size, so I created a default class as well that basically has all base font sizes. After that, go over to your tailwind.config and add your variables like so:


 fontSize: {
  xs: ['var(--text-xs)', 'var(--line-height-xs)'],
  sm: ['var(--text-sm)', 'var(--line-height-sm)'],
  base: ['var(--text-base)', 'var(--line-height-base)'],
  lg: ['var(--text-lg)', 'var(--line-height-lg)'],
  xl: ['var(--text-xl)', 'var(--line-height-xl)'],
  '2xl': ['var(--text-2xl)', 'var(--line-height-2xl)'],
  '3xl': ['var(--text-3xl)', 'var(--line-height-3xl)'],
  '4xl': ['var(--text-4xl)', 'var(--line-height-4xl)'],
  '5xl': ['var(--text-5xl)', 'var(--line-height-base)'],
  '6xl': ['var(--text-6xl)', 'var(--line-height-base)'],
  '7xl': ['var(--text-7xl)', 'var(--line-height-base)'],
  '8xl': ['var(--text-8xl)', 'var(--line-height-base)'],
  '9xl': ['var(--text-9xl)', 'var(--line-height-base)'],
 },



Finally, go to your swticher button and, onClick, add the following using the useTheme hook from next-themes:


onClick={() => setTheme('big')}



The same for the default. By the way, it may or may not change the font right the way, what I did was reload the page when the user wants to swtich back (I used a modal to ask if they're sure first).
It's not the most clever solution but it's what I'm using right now since I can't think of something better. I hope it helps!
By the way, be careful with the versions of next-themes, because it broke my build and I had to downgrade.
